# Intel wireless works only when acpi=off on 16.04

Tags: power-management, thinkpad, acpi, 16.04

I've bought recently brand new ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th generation, trying to set up Ubuntu 16.04 (beta 2 at moment of writing).

Can't get wireless and ACPI working **together**, they kind of exclude each other:

1. Wireless perfectly works only and only if `acpi=off` is passed to kernel
2. But if `acpi=off` is set, full power management system is off, as a result no battery status, no suspend to RAM, no audio (for some reason, it works when ACPI is on), etc

Any clues why wireless works only if `acpi=off` is set? I need to get rid of `acpi=off` because I need power management.

```
Linux alex-carbon-x1 4.4.0-15-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:08:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 9d35 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d12 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-V (rev 21)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

Comment: 16.04 is off-topic until it is released.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure this is not related to the 16.10 itself.

Comment: Anyway it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: Make sure you're on the latest BIOS for your system.

Comment: Since this is super latest thinkpad 4th gen which was released a month ago, I believe it has most up to date BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get both ACPI and wireless working use `acpi=force` option instead of `acpi=off`.